# Anonymous type, cast as AsQueryable from an if statement and then queried

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have this if statement, which returns the result as a AsQueryable to an anonymous type:

```
If (signature = "") Then
                testResults = (From TRTable In context.TestResults
                                        Where ((TRTable.Art_no = currentProduct) And (TRTable.Server_time > startDate) And (TRTable.Server_time < endDate))
                                        Select TRTable.Art_no, TRTable.Failed, TRTable.Retested).AsQueryable
            ElseIf (signInfo = "out") Then
                testResults = (From TRTable In context.TestResults
                                        Where ((TRTable.Art_no = currentProduct) And (TRTable.Server_time > startDate) And (TRTable.Server_time < endDate) And TRTable.Sign <> signature)
                                        Select TRTable.Art_no, TRTable.Failed, TRTable.Retested).AsQueryable
            Else
                testResults = (From TRTable In context.TestResults
                                        Where ((TRTable.Art_no = currentProduct) And (TRTable.Server_time > startDate) And (TRTable.Server_time < endDate) And TRTable.Sign = signature)
                                        Select TRTable.Art_no, TRTable.Failed, TRTable.Retested).AsQueryable
            End If
```

And then when I do

```
StatisticsModel.Passed = testResults.Where(Function(p) p.Failed = 0).Count
```

I get

```
Method invocation failed because 'Public Function Where(predicate As String, ParamArray parameters As System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter()) As System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[VB$AnonymousType_3`3[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable(Of VB$AnonymousType_3(Of String,Nullable(Of Decimal),Nullable(Of Decimal)))' cannot be called with these arguments:
Argument matching parameter 'predicate' cannot convert from 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_1(Of Object,Object)' to 'String'.
```

Sorry for the long line of text, but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working, it was working without the if statement, but I need that functionality.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the `System.Linq.Queryable.Where` extension method, but your code thinks you want `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.Where`.

Make sure you have the correct `Imports System.Linq` statement at the top of your file.  If that doesn't work, you might have to directly call `System.Linq.Queryable.Where(testResults, ...).Count`.  You could also use `Count(predicate)` instead of `Where(predicate).Count`, which might also avoid the conflict.

Comment: It seems asif directly calling works, but now that I have explicitly stated the testResults before the if statement, it gives me a nullreference exception. Any way I can work around that?

Comment: From what I can see, all 3 branches of your `If` statement will correctly set the value of `testResults`.  As long as the `Where(...).Count` code is after your `If` block (and there are no other `If` paths), then you shouldn't be getting a `null reference` exception.

Comment: You could also just do a quick check for null (`If testResults IsNot Nothing Then ...`)

Comment: It seems asif it returns the nullexception when the Where method is called, tried doing it without the Count, and it doesn't work. It just suggest me to use the "new" keyword =/

Comment: Also, I tried debugging it, turns out it is actually nothing.

Comment: Well, with any `null reference` exception, you need to track down exactly where and what is causing it.  In your last line of code, the `null` could be coming from any of these: `StatisticsModel`, `testResults`, or even `p.Failed`.  Try to locate **where**, and you'll probably figure out **why**.